# Java simulation of multiple client login

Tags: java, multithreading

i have written a client Java program supposed to get userid and password , then pass them to an external program to do some processing. Basically doing some I/O. Below is rough sketch of my program.

```
public class Client{
    /* this part gets userid and password*/
     ....
    String userid = <...>
    String password = <...>

    /* this part do I/O */        
    cmd = ".... -u userid -p password ..."; //this external command will write some files to disk
    ProcessBuilder pb = .......;
    pb.start() ; //run external program
    ....        
}
```

Many users will be using this program so I just want to know, if I don't want performance issues when many users connect at the same time( thereby doing a lot of I/O ),  I would need to use JAva threading? How can I change the code to take care of many users. Also on a Windows system, how can i simulate many users , for testing this program. thanks

Comment: for testing many users, you can use jmeter

Comment: about threads, processbuilder is not thread safe (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) then you have to synchronize externally

Comment: hi leo, how do you synchronize externally ? thanks

Comment: thanks for recommending jmeter. Right now I don't have time to read through how to use it. Am thinking of just using the DOS command `start /min` to simulate the users . Any comments on this method? thanks

Comment: The performance problems, if any, are likely to be in the server rather than in the client. Except, perhaps, for your proposed many-logons-at-once scenario, which will indeed want to be multithreaded and may want to be spread across multiple machines to better simulate that load.

Comment: @dorothy good question :-) I am having a quite similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744848/thread-safe-way-to-call-an-external-process-and-grab-its-output-stream-from-in

Comment: maybe wrapping inside a thread is enough, but I am not sure. Maybe someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would replicate your environment into a test environment and in my local environment I would write two test-codes:

- a code which would generate many users
- another code which would use your code as if there were many users

Now, I would test this algorithm with the mentioned approaches and would measure the response time in the test code. After enough tests I would have an answer whether a single-threaded solution is ok or multi-threading approach should be preferred. Cheers.